# Why doesn't Perl threading work when I call readdir beforehand?

Tags: multithreading, perl, readdir

Whenever I call readdir before I create a thread, I get an error that looks like this:

```
perl(2820,0x7fff70c33ca0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10082e600: pointer 
being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

What's strange is that it happens when I call readdir before I create a thread (i.e. readdir is not called in any concurrent code). I don't even use the results from readdir, just making the call to it seems to screw things up. When I get rid of it, things seem to work fine. Some example code is below:

```
opendir(DIR, $someDir);
my @allFiles = readdir(DIR);
close(DIR);

my $thread = threads->create(\&sub1);
$thread->join();

sub sub1 {
print "in thread\n"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use closedir, not close, to close a directory handle.
Fixing that makes this work correctly, though the symtom I see with close() is a little different:

```
*** glibc detected *** perl: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x09bc7d28 ***
```

However, this should still be reported as a bug, since it should be perfectly ok to leave the directory handle to be automatically closed at the end of the program.

Comment: I'm not sure how to characterize the bug: is it that `close()` does not detect that it was given a directory handle instead of a file handle (and leave well alone after reporting the error appropriately)?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: the dirhandle/filehandle thing is a design bug in perl5; every glob is *both*.  and closing an already closed (or never opened) filehandle "just in case" is perfectly legitimate; it shouldn't give a warning, though close() does return an error.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: minimum code to reproduce the bug has nothing to do with close/closedir, really: `use threads; opendir(DIR,"."); threads->new(sub{})->join`

Answer (score 0):

You will have problems with open dirhandles with all versions of perl up to latest (or two) development version - this problem was fixed recently.

P.S. Use lexical dirhandles.